# Does Grails run the Bootstrap.groovy script when deploying the app as a war?

Tags: grails

Bootstrap executes fine during run-app (database is seeded). But it doesn't appear to get invoked when Tomcat deploys the war (nothing in the database).

Does the Bootstrap get run during war deployment? If not, is there a way to make it run?

Specifically I am wanting my sample data to seed the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does....

i would look to make sure you have your environments configured properly if you see thing working in development, but not production

Comment: The env was out of whack. I running a Hudson build using 'grails dev clean compile' - not realizing multiple targets are not valid.

Comment: And the solution is to use -Dgrails.env=dev as apparently the prepending of the env doesn't get forwarded to the war (tomact plugin) command.